# Unexpected result in a DGC test - unreferenced() method

Tags: java, rmi

I'm doing some tests about the Java RMI Distributed GC.

This is my test project:

**SERVER SIDE**

Bootstrap.java

```
public interface Bootstrap extends Remote
{

    public Runnable getClient() throws RemoteException;

}
```

Login.java

```
public interface Login extends Remote
{

    public String login() throws RemoteException;

}
```

BootstrapServer.java

```
public class BootstrapServer implements Bootstrap, Unreferenced
{

    private final Login loginServerStub;

    public BootstrapServer(Login loginServerStub, int port)
            throws RemoteException
    {
        this.loginServerStub = loginServerStub;

        UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this, port);
    }

    @Override
    public Runnable getClient() throws RemoteException
    {
        return new Client(loginServerStub);
    }

    @Override
    public void unreferenced()
    {
        System.out.println("unreferenced() method called on BootstrapServer");
    }

}
```

LoginServer.java

```
public class LoginServer implements Login, Unreferenced
{

    public LoginServer(int port) throws RemoteException
    {
        UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this, port);
    }

    @Override
    public String login() throws RemoteException
    {
        return "Login successful";
    }

    @Override
    public void unreferenced()
    {
        System.out.println("unreferenced() method called on LoginServer");
    }

}
```

Client.java

```
public class Client implements Runnable, Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2743368372506517302L;
    private final Login loginServerStub;


    public Client(Login loginServerStub)
    {
        this.loginServerStub = loginServerStub;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Hi! I'm the client.");
        System.out.println("This is the remote reference of the login server:");
        System.out.println(loginServerStub + "\n");
        System.out.println("I'm trying to invoke the login method:");

        try
        {
            System.out.println(loginServerStub.login());
        }
        catch (RemoteException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

Setup.java

```
public class Setup
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null)
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());

        Bootstrap bootstrapServer = null;
        try
        {
            Login loginServer = new LoginServer(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
            bootstrapServer = new BootstrapServer(loginServer,
                    Integer.parseInt(args[1]));

            LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
            Registry rmiRegistry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            rmiRegistry.bind("BootstrapServer", bootstrapServer);
        }
        catch (RemoteException | AlreadyBoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

}
```

The important thing is that the BootstrapServer maintains a remote reference of LoginServer.
When a client calls the getClient() method, the BootstrapServer creates a new Client object.
Within the Client object is encapsulated the remote reference of LoginServer.
Finally, the Client object is serialized and it is sent to the client side application.

---

**CLIENT SIDE**

ClientBootstrap.java

```
public class ClientBootstrap
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null)
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());

        Runnable client = null;
        try
        {
            Bootstrap bootstrapServer = (Bootstrap)
                    Naming.lookup("//" + args[0] + ":1099/BootstrapServer");
            client = bootstrapServer.getClient();           
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException | RemoteException | NotBoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        client.run();        
    }

}
```

The client side application just runs the Client object sent by the server.

---

This is the output of client side application:

```
user@ubuntu:~/javarmi/UnreferencedTestClient$ ./client_launcher.sh 
Hi! I'm the client.
This is the remote reference of the login server:
LoginServer_Stub[UnicastRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[127.0.1.1:42000](remote),objID:[711ad51f:148ebcdecc7:-7fff, 6312833096912673336]]]]

I'm trying to invoke the login method:
Login successful
user@ubuntu:~/javarmi/UnreferencedTestClient$
```

After one minute (I changed the leaseValue and the checkInterval parameters) the server side application prints:

```
unreferenced() method called on LoginServer
```

Note that the unreferenced() method on BootstrapServer is never called (because of rmiregistry maintains a remote reference).

The question is: why the unreferenced() method is called on LoginServer if the BootstrapServer has got the *loginServerStub* reference?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the server JVM, the `BootstrapServer` *doesn't* have a `loginStub` reference. It has a reference to the actual server. Remote object, not its stub. You've misnamed the variable. So, as there is no *remote* connection between `BootStrapServer` and `LoginServer`, the former isn't a DGC client of the matter, so the latter can get DGC'd.

The client JVM has exited, so there are no DGC clients of anything anywhere, so there's nothing there to prevent DGC either.

Comment: Does the BootstrapServer haven't a remote reference because that reference isn't passed as a parameter of a remote method?

Comment: EDIT: I tried to add a remote method in the BootstrapServer to pass the reference of the login server as a parameter of this new method instead of using the constructor. But the result is the same, the reference is not a stub. I don't understand why it is passed the local reference instead of the stub to the remote object, this is what the documentation says about: "When passing an exported remote object as a parameter or return value in a remote method call, the stub for that remote object is passed instead."

Comment: You seem to be asking about what happens in the client: so see my second paragraph. You're correct to say the remote object is serialized as its own stub upon serialization, but as the client JVM exits immediately, there is still no surviving DGC client, so DGC can occur, so `unreferenced()` is called.

Comment: I understand that :) What it's not clear for me is why the bootstrap server has a local reference instead of a remote reference.

Comment: Because you stored the result of `new LoginServer(...)` into it, which is a remote object, not a stub. You misnamed the constructor parameter and local variable as `loginServerStub`, but that alone doesn't make it a stub. I don't understand why you don't understand your own code.

Comment: The result of the `new LoginServer(...)` is a *exported* remote object, this is ok.

Now, the documentation says: "When passing an exported remote object as a parameter or return value in a remote method call, the stub for that remote object is passed instead."

But in my case, it seems that the remote reference is passed not its stub. This is the point of my code that I don't understand (of course, it's a test).

Comment: If you're talking about the client, which is the only thing that calls remote methods here, you're right, but the client JVM exits, so there is no DGC client. If you're talking about the server, there is no remote method being called, so no occasion for translation of remote objects to stubs.

Comment: I was talking about the server. Thank you for explanation.